# IP Validation & URL Validation if elseif statement?

Tags: php, validation

Edit.

Any ideas why this would not work? I added the 'FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE' flag and I also added a check to see if localhost was input (maybe there is another way, when i was reading it says 'FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE' does not filter it), but it does not seem to work.

```
$post_input = 'google.com'; // IP or a URL goes here

$targets = array("localhost", "127.0.0.1", "127.1"); // The array of words / values

if (!filter_var($post_input, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) 
// The above validates IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE is so 192.168.1.1 etc do not work (but it is nto working).

    && filter_var($post_input, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)
    // The above validates IP, this is fine.

    && in_array($post_input, $targets)) 
    // The above checks against the array above, if the input contains this, do not continue, go to 'Invalid IP or URL'.
{
    echo 'Invalid IP or URL';
} else {
    echo 'good';
}
```

Note: I removed the '!' for the URL verification, that was intentional if you were wondering.

// -------------------------------------------------

I know I am not doing this correct, but I don't know how I would do this.

I want the input to either be an IP or a URL. If it is an IP, it will check if it is valid, then skip over the URL validation. If it is a URL, it will get validated, then skip over the IP validation

Is there an easy way to do this?

```
$post_data = '216.58.216.174';
$post_data = 'http://google.com'; // Could also be this

if (!filter_var($post_data, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) { /* Validate IP */
    echo 'Invalid IP';
}elseif (!filter_var($post_data, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { /* Validate URL */
    echo 'Invalid URL';
}else {
    echo 'All Good';
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/17150100/632951 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
if (!filter_var($post_data, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && !filter_var($post_data, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { /* Validate IP */
    echo 'Invalid IP or URL';
} else {
    echo 'All Good';
}
```

Reviewing your edit, you should try the following:

```
$post_input = 'http://google.com';
$targets = array("localhost", "127.0.0.1", "127.1"); 
if ((!filter_var($post_input, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) 
   && !filter_var($post_input, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
   || in_array($post_input, $targets))
{
    echo 'Invalid IP or URL';
} else {
    echo 'good';
}
```

Carefull, `google.com` won't validate with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`, `http://google.com` will.

That way, the results will be the following:

- `http://google.com` → good.
- `192.168.0.1` → Invalid IP or URL.
- `69.23.43.12` or whatever valid IP → good.
- Array contents → Invalid IP or URL.

Comment: Now, I'm not sure what you are trying to archive. Please explain better all the inputs and the expected outputs.

Comment: Edited to explain better

Answer (score 2):

I think must be like this :

```
if (filter_var($post_data, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) { /* Validate IP */
    echo 'This is valid IP';
}elseif (filter_var($post_data, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { /* Validate URL */
    echo 'This is valid URL';
}else {
    echo 'This is not either IP or URL';
}
```